# XML Query Question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query, xml

I'm trying to generate a SQL query to get the "DATE" values out of the following SQL XML:

[image: ScreenShot]

I've tried something like this but I don't think I'm understanding the concepts.

```
select 
   xConfig.value('(/SearchjobConfig/QueryString/SearchCriteria/ExpressionSet/SimpleAttributeExpression) [1]','nvarchar(max)') 
from 
    Job
```

Here is the XML as text:

```xml
<SearchJobConfig>
  <QueryID>1072</QueryID>
  <QueryString>
    <SearchCriteria name="Search query" >
      <ExpressionSet logicalOperator="AND">
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Date" npmPropertyId="4" searchOperation="GREATER_EQUAL" dataType="string" caseSensitive="false">2019-06-01T04:00:00</SimpleAttributeExpression>
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Date" npmPropertyId="4" searchOperation="LESS_EQUAL" dataType="string" caseSensitive="false">2019-06-13T03:59:59</SimpleAttributeExpression>
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Class" npmPropertyId="1056" searchOperation="EQUALS" dataType="int32" caseSensitive="false">65</SimpleAttributeExpression>
      </ExpressionSet>
    </SearchCriteria>
  </QueryString>
</SearchJobConfig>
```

The expected output would be the Dates:

```
2019-06-01T04:00:00
2019-06-13T03:59:59
```

and what would it take to get the results on the same line.. example:

```
date_val_start date_val_end 2019-06-01T04:00:00 2019-06-13T03:59:59
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 8):

Does this get you what you want?

```
DECLARE @x XML = '
<SearchJobConfig>
  <QueryID>1072</QueryID>
  <QueryString>
    <SearchCriteria name="Search query" >
      <ExpressionSet logicalOperator="AND">
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Date" npmPropertyId="4" searchOperation="GREATER_EQUAL" dataType="string" caseSensitive="false">2019-06-01T04:00:00</SimpleAttributeExpression>
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Date" npmPropertyId="4" searchOperation="LESS_EQUAL" dataType="string" caseSensitive="false">2019-06-13T03:59:59</SimpleAttributeExpression>
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Class" npmPropertyId="1056" searchOperation="EQUALS" dataType="int32" caseSensitive="false">65</SimpleAttributeExpression>
      </ExpressionSet>
    </SearchCriteria>
  </QueryString>
</SearchJobConfig>
'

DECLARE @Job TABLE(xConfig XML)

INSERT @Job ( xConfig )
VALUES ( @x )

SELECT j.*
       , ca.c.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS date_val
FROM @Job AS j
CROSS APPLY j.xConfig.nodes('/SearchJobConfig/QueryString/SearchCriteria/ExpressionSet/SimpleAttributeExpression') AS ca(c)
WHERE ca.c.exist('@displayName[.= "Date"]') = 1;
```

To get everything on one line, just do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT N' ' + ca.c.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
     FROM @Job AS j
     CROSS APPLY j.xConfig.nodes('/SearchJobConfig/QueryString/SearchCriteria/ExpressionSet/SimpleAttributeExpression') AS ca(c)
     WHERE ca.c.exist('@displayName[.= "Date"]') = 1
     FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE ).value(N'.[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, N'') 
) AS x(date_val);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the date values in the same row but different columns you can shred using `nodes()` to get one row per `ExpressionSet` node and then use attributes `displayName` and `searchOption` in `value()` to get start and end date.

```
declare @x xml = '
<SearchJobConfig>
  <QueryID>1072</QueryID>
  <QueryString>
    <SearchCriteria name="Search query" >
      <ExpressionSet logicalOperator="AND">
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Date" npmPropertyId="4" searchOperation="GREATER_EQUAL" dataType="string" caseSensitive="false">2019-06-01T04:00:00</SimpleAttributeExpression>
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Date" npmPropertyId="4" searchOperation="LESS_EQUAL" dataType="string" caseSensitive="false">2019-06-13T03:59:59</SimpleAttributeExpression>
        <SimpleAttributeExpression displayName="Class" npmPropertyId="1056" searchOperation="EQUALS" dataType="int32" caseSensitive="false">65</SimpleAttributeExpression>
      </ExpressionSet>
    </SearchCriteria>
  </QueryString>
</SearchJobConfig>
';
declare @Job table(xConfig xml);
insert @Job (xConfig) values (@x);

select T.X.value('(SimpleAttributeExpression
                   [
                    @displayName = "Date" and 
                    @searchOperation = "GREATER_EQUAL"
                   ]/text())[1]', 'datetime') as date_val_start,
       T.X.value('(SimpleAttributeExpression
                   [
                    @displayName = "Date" and 
                    @searchOperation = "LESS_EQUAL"
                   ]/text())[1]', 'datetime') as date_val_end
from @Job as j
  cross apply j.xConfig.nodes('/SearchJobConfig/QueryString/
                                SearchCriteria/ExpressionSet') as T(X);
```

Result:

```
date_val_start            date_val_end
2019-06-01 04:00:00.000   2019-06-13 03:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to retrieve multiple values from the XML, but then instructing your XPath to return only the *first* (#1) of them:

```
/ SearchjobConfig / QueryString / SearchCriteria / ExpressionSet / SimpleAttributeExpression [ 1 ]
                                                                                             \___/
                                                                     Returns indexed item #1 _/
```

Lose this indexing clause and you'll get *both* values back, in the order they appear within the input XML.

Further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

As far as getting them into a single line ...   it's [almost certainly] possibly, but is it really worth the effort for only two of them?  YMMV.